# What does threshold do for a matrix profile?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, profile, feature-extraction, matrix-profile

[image: Matrix profiles with both threshold 0.99 and 0]

So I've plot these two matrix profiles by using the `tsfresh` feature extraction libraries and I've verified that these two graphs are identical (through `gimp`) and now my question is, `what does the threshold do, if it's not giving a big impact on the graph`? I read that the threshold has to be in between 0 and 1 and these values don't seem to impact this feature.

Could someone help me understand what the threshold does?

Thank you!

#edit

https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/tsfresh/feature_extraction/feature_calculators.html#matrix_profile

for ease of research :)

Answer (score 0):

Without setting a window size, the Pan Matrix Profile is computed instead of a single Matrix Profile. It's a stack of Matrix Profiles with different window sizes; in this case Threshold determines the maximum window to be used. Any window with an above-threshold correlation to the full sequence is calculated. The problem might be not setting a window size with the mean preprocessing, which takes a separate window parameter.
https://matrixprofile.docs.matrixprofile.org/api.html#matrixprofile-compute

It's probably easiest to specify "windows" to get a single or set of matrix profiles calculated with those window sizes. And with mean preprocessing, its own individual window size.